# unable to access jarfile app.jar и 503 service unavailable

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot

Столкнулся  стакой проблемой.

сервис на spring boot, java 8,

докер файл

```
FROM alpine_jdk1.8.0_181

COPY docker/app.jar /app/

RUN mkdir /app/logs

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /app

CMD echo $(( $(cat /app/.stat 2>/dev/null || echo 0) + 1 )) > /app/.stat ; \
    java -Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 $JAVA_OPTS -jar app.jar $CMD_ARGS --migration.enabled=$(if [ "$(cat /app/.stat)" -eq "1" ] && [ "$MIGRATION_ENABLED" = "true" ] ; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi)
```

принимает на обработку json запросы. размер запроса может доходить до 30-40 мб.

Проблема: периодически после 5-20 запросов (т.е. число запросов рандомное)

сервис дает ответ на post запрос : 503 service unavailable

контейнер начинает рестартиться. (задеплоин с 2 ГБ памяти)

В логах контейнера ошибка
Error: Unable to access jarfile app.jar

я не очень понимаю, где копать источник ошибки. Запрос отрабатывает нормально и уход в перезагрузку начинается рандомно, даже когда запросы на вход не идут.

Comment: Такое впечатление, что у вас в системе число открытых файлов лимитировано. Что выдает команда `ulimit`? А команда `lsof | wc -l`? Какие настройки в файле `/etc/security/limits.conf`? Можете помониторить, сколько файлов открывает ваш докер - `lsof <docker-pid> | wc -l`?

Comment: да спасибо за предложение